# Can i write short path in XPath?

Tags: xpath

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a> 
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">SO</a>
        <div>
             <div class="kekeke">JSAFK</div>
        </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

For getting a JSAFK element in this doc, using XPath, can I just write `//*div[@class=kekeke]` instead full XPath?

Comment: `//div[@class="kekeke"]/text()`

Answer (score 2):

`//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.  So...

This XPath,

```
//div[@class='kekeke']
```

will select all such `div` elements in the document:

```
<div class="kekeke">JSAFK</div>
```

This XPath,

```
//div[@class='kekeke']/text()
```

will select all text nodes under all such `div` elements in the document:

```
JSAFK
```

Answer (score 0):

there is  something wrong in "

```
 //*div[@class=kekeke]
```

you can't use * and div together. if you want to have a shorter path.
you can write like this

```
//div[@class="kekeke"]/text()
```